# Excel: Fill every cell with ID numbers in ascending order

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am new in this community. I recently started to learn using Microsoft Office Excel. I know this question is very simple and may be answered somewhere, but anyways I'd like to know how can I input ID numbers in a certain range in a single column sorted in ascending order?

> **Example:** Ranging from row **2** to row **5** in column **A**, I'd like to input the number **1**, then I want it to automatically increase in number for the remaining cells.

```
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────
  1 | ID  |     |     |
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────
  2 | 001 |     |     |
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────
  3 | 002 |     |     |
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────
  4 | 003 |     |     |
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────
  5 | 004 |     |     |
```

But what I get when I do it is all cells have the value of 1. How can I achieve that?

My Office version is Professional Plus 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many rows you want, the simplest way is to put 1 on A2, and 2 on A3. Hightlight both A2 and A3, and then move your mouse to the bottom-right-corner of the selection box, and drag down.

It will then "continue" the selection and the next line would be 3, 4, 5 and so on.

If you need them in that particular format (001, 002, 003), you just need to select all the rows and format the cells to "Custom" and enter 000, and it will be displayed accordingly.